# Regular Expression not contain a word list

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression
to match a string which not contains some specific words and following it by a certain word like this:

```
(?<!(state|government|head).*)of
```

ex:

```
state of -> not match
government of -> not match
Abc of -> match
```

But It doesn't work. I don't know why, please help me explain it.

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? Is it matching incorrectly, are you getting no matches, etc.?

Comment: the syntax of the regex is not correct, so strings not matched

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex with **Negative lookahead**. The sample like:

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?!state|government|head).*$");
        String s = "state of";
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        boolean bl = matcher.find();
        System.out.println(bl);

        s = "government of";
        matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        bl = matcher.find();
        System.out.println(bl);

        s = "Abc of";
        matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        bl = matcher.find();
        System.out.println(bl);
    }
```

Hope this help!